# Does "Slow" only slow down enemies' walking speed or does it also slow their attackt?

Tags: diablo-iii

[Hwoj Wrap](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hwoj-wrap) makes Locust Swarm "Slow" enemies by up to 80%.

I wonder if it slows enemies attack speed too?

Answer (score 4):

If the description simply mentions "**Slow**", it is only movement speed.

There are several skills that influence enemy attack speed, most notably Wizard's Slow Time, but those always explicitly state "**slows enemy attack speed by x%**".

Answer (score 2):

As per [the Diablo Wikia](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Slow), the Slow debuff only affects movement speed. From my own experience as well, there is nothing that slows down enemy attack speed. Chilled effects can affect attack speed by slowing down enemy animations, [thus allowing you to dodge more easily](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5911943682).

Comment: Wizard's slow time slows the attack speed, but it shows it in the tooltip for the spell.